# Postgresql: reduce memory requirements of insert from select

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a time-series database in Postgresql, using the [timescaledb](https://www.timescale.com/) extension.

I have a table of bid/ask data for the USD/EUR currency pair:

```
CREATE TABLE fx_quotes_raw_eurusd
(
    time       TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    bid_price  DOUBLE PRECISION,
    ask_price  DOUBLE PRECISION
)
```

It is a timescale hypertable:

```
SELECT create_hypertable('fx_quotes_raw_eurusd', 'time', 
                         if_not_exists => TRUE, 
                         migrate_data => TRUE)
```

It contains roughly 100,000,000 rows

```
db=# select count(*) from fx_quotes_raw_eurusd;
   count  
-----------
 114242586
(1 row)
```

I now want to quantise the raw data into 1 minute periods:

```
INSERT INTO fx_quotes_1_min_eurusd
    (time, bid_price, ask_price)
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 minute', time::TIMESTAMP) + interval '1 minute' as interval,
    last(bid_price, time),
    last(ask_price, time)
FROM
    fx_quotes_raw_eurusd
GROUP BY
    interval
ORDER BY
    interval
```

The issue I'm having is the memory requirements for this query are too large for my computer to handle.

I have managed to work around the issue by chunking the data into 1 year blocks:

```
INSERT INTO fx_quotes_1_min_eurusd
    (time, bid_price, ask_price)
SELECT
    time_bucket('1 minute', time::TIMESTAMP) + interval '1 minute' as interval,
    last(bid_price, time),
    last(ask_price, time)
FROM
    fx_quotes_raw_eurusd
WHERE
    time >= '2001-01-01'
AND
    time < '2002-01-01'
GROUP BY
    interval
ORDER BY
    interval
```

and then repeating this for each year, over and over again, until I've quantised the entire range.

It seems a bit clunky, and I'm wondering if there is a better way to formulate my query so that the memory requirements aren't so large?

Comment: Reduce `work_mem`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, I'll have a look into it. I did a `show all` and see it's set to the default value of `4MB`, and I have `16GB` ram on my machine... so I'm not sure why it's using so much ram - maybe because of timescale? I'm not sure...